# UIApplication sharedApplication keyWindow - iOS App Widget

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiapplication, keywindow

I have a simple app and widget for iOS 8. I am making use of the UIImage+ImageEffects source files. One of the functions in that library is called "convertViewToImage" which contains the following code:

```
+ (UIImage *)convertViewToImage
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return capturedScreen;
}
```

However, the first line of that method comes us with an error when compiling in an app extension.

`UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];`

Comes up with the following error:

> sharedApplicaion is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

Does anyone know how I can go about fixing this issue?

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you cant access the Shared application in an extension. So here are some different ways to achieve what you want.

try using the snapshotVieAfterScreenUpdates method

```
[self.myViewToConvertToImage snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

This returns a UIView that is a snapshot of the complex view.

alternatively if your after a UIImage to do some processing with

try

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```